# Optimising mongodb schema

Tags: mongodb, optimization, schema

I have mongodb schema

```
{
  MyProduct: "testProduct_1",
  Module:    "Module_1",
  CreatedTime: "24-08-2009",
  MyMessage: "SomeMessage"

}
```

However MyProduct and Module are most of the time repeated entries, so I don't want to log it every time. How can I optimise this schema so that MyProduct and Module  are written only once and (CreatedTime,MyMessage) are updated every time.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a NoSQL solution like MongoDB if you're asking questions like this? Look at the accepted answer at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553860/nosql-use-case-scenarios-or-when-to-use-nosql

Answer (score 1):

The best optimization which I would do is to substitute your stringDate as a normal date ([timestamp](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/#timestamps) or [date](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/#date)).

If you really want to optimize your myproduct/module, you can push it to application layer implementing the logic. If there is no `module`, than take `myProduct` thus storing it only if it is different.

Keep in mind that it is important to know what are you planning to do with your data before doing any kind of optimizations.