# I wanted to know specific use cases for document-oriented databases?

Tags: document-oriented-db

I am searching in the internet, I also did a search in stackoverflow but i didnt find a proper or appropriate use-case for this type of databases. 
And if you guys could tell me what kind of applications are better done with document oriented databases instead of relational databases.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there probably isn't a good answer on SO, because this forum isn't very well suited to this kind of problem... if you have trouble implementing one, then maybe this would be a good place...

Answer (score 0):

I will give you one small use case but generally stackoverflow is all about programming and this is off topic.

Nevertheless Document oriented Databases or NOSQL DBs are for example used if your data that you want to put into your DB have a different amount of columns. if you would put this data into an RDB you would end up with many empty fields and that might be undesirable. in a NOSQL DB you only store the fields that are necessary.

Maybe Wikipedia will help you too:

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL

EDIT:

Actually there is a Stackoverflow question answering that:

[NoSQL Use Case Scenarios or WHEN to use NoSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553860/nosql-use-case-scenarios-or-when-to-use-nosql)

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. I wanted to know what  applications could use that?  even if a simple one, just to show me that they are useful.

Comment: That should answer your question: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553860/nosql-use-case-scenarios-or-when-to-use-nosql

If it does, you can close this question here.

Comment: Well, for example, if I want to develop a blog, will I be better with a relational or with a document?