# Can i use Nosql Databases like Mongodb for my Scenario

Tags: sql-server, mongodb

I have manufacturing company data in a relational form and have around 10 tables each table has more than 300 columns .we have set of operations to be performed (like join ,union ,ranking) sequentially to reach a final aggregated table which will be used for analysis but during joins its crossing more than 1000 columns which is not supported by relational database.What is the best database to use for such scenarios? 
do they support all SQL operations?

currently we are using SQL Server

Comment: it really depends on the use case if and which nosql db is suited at all. usually they only provide a subset of sql operations. see also here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553860/nosql-use-case-scenarios-or-when-to-use-nosql